Fetching values from database and show in an array as a php variable is not working
I have a holidays table where company_id and off_days are two columns which have multiple rows. I have created a function nextWorkingDay() to skip Friday and holidays depend on company_id. In the function I showed if company_id is 1 or 2 then should skip Friday and holiday else just add 1 day with the current_date. When I run the function the date skips Friday only for company_id 1 but holidays are not skipping. Couldn't find out the error.
In my view file I have call the method to fetch data from database according to company_id. In this case company_id = 1.
In the Model file I write the query like this:
public function read_company_offdays($company_id) {
    $sql = 'SELECT off_days FROM hr_holidays WHERE company_id = "'.$company_id.'"';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
       return $query->result();
    } else {
       return null;
    }
}

And the off_days are '2024-01-06','2024-01-07' for company_id 1.
$offdays = $this->Payroll_model->read_company_offdays($company_id);

$holidays = array();
foreach($offdays as $r){
    $holidays[] = $r->off_days;
}

function isHoliday($date) {
    global $holidays;
    return in_array($date, $holidays);
}

function getNextWorkingDay($date) {

    $nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1 day'));
    
    while (date('N', strtotime($nextDay)) == 5 || isHoliday($nextDay)) {
        $nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($nextDay . ' +1 day'));
    }
    
    return $nextDay;
}

$companyId = $company_id;
$currentDate = '2024-01-04';

if ($companyId == 1 || $companyId == 2) {
    $nextDay = getNextWorkingDay($currentDate);
} else {
    $nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate . ' +1 day'));
}

In View File I echoed like this <?php echo $nextDay;?> and the Output shows '2024-01-06' but it should be '2024-01-08' if considers holidays. Couldn't figure out the issue in my code!
I have solved the issue. Thanks anyways. I am sharing the updated code below for reference.
// Function to check if a date is between two specific dates
function isBetweenDates($date, $startDate, $endDate) {
    return strtotime($date) >= strtotime($startDate) && strtotime($date) <= strtotime($endDate);
}

// Function to get the next working day
function getNextWorkingDay($date, $startDate, $endDate) {
    $nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1 day')); // Get the next day
    
    // If the resulting date is Friday, add one more day
    if (date('N', strtotime($nextDay)) == 5) {
        $nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($nextDay . ' +1 day'));
    }
    
    // If the resulting date falls between two specific dates, add one more day with the last of two dates
    if (isBetweenDates($nextDay, $startDate, $endDate)) {
        $nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate . ' +1 day'));
    }
    
    return $nextDay;
}

// Main code
$companyId = $company_id; // Example company ID
$currentDate = $att_cmd[0]->cmd_date; // Current date
$startDate = $offdays[0]->start_date;
$endDate = $offdays[0]->end_date;

if ($companyId == 1 || $companyId == 2) {
    // Check if the next day is Friday or Holiday
    $nextDay = getNextWorkingDay($currentDate, $startDate, $endDate);
} else {
    // For other company IDs, simply output the next day
    $nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate . ' +1 day'));
}


What does the off_days value look like in the database? Does it always contain a single date (so you have multiple rows for the same company with one date per row) or is it string with multiple dates separated by commas, like this: '2024-01-06','2024-01-07'? If I assume the first case, your code gives me 2024-01-08, and it gives me 2024-01-06 for the second case, so that might be where your problem is?
